# Remove get parameters from URL in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, url, get

I've got a support ticket system that sends out emails with specific links to the tickets.  Here's an example link:

"taptap.com/tt_dev/taptapeat/?iTicket_ID=11#/app/controller/ticket

This prepopulates the ticket page with the id and fills it.
Now, the problem is that I don't want the "?iTicket_ID=11" to stick around.  So I've tried a couple of things:

First, I'm correctly generating a url that doesn't have the get parameters and works just fine.  I can easily get "taptap.com/tt_dev/taptapeat/#/app/controller/ticket" from the above link.

Upon entry into the page, I've tried running both of these lines of code:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/" + newUrl);
// and
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/" + newUrl);
```

These lines of code, even if ran AFTER the ticket populates, wipes all the information from the page.  It's as if it never ran in the first place.  Here's the line I'm running BEFORE running the above code:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
$scope.ticketData.ticket.iTicket_ID = urlParams.get('iTicket_ID');
```

But these lines don't seem to do anything.

So instead, I'm also trying to do it in the "leave" function:

```
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
     window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/" + newUrl); 
  });
```

This doesn't do anything at all - in the page I arrive at after leaving, my get parameters persist.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: "_But these lines don't seem to do anything._" What does `window.location.search` returns?

Comment: @palaѕн This gets the current url.

Comment: what does `console.log( window.location.search )` returns? Is can not return current url, as you are using `search` property of the location.

Comment: Oh yes, this returns the get parameter string.  In this case, &iTicket_ID=11

Comment: Then your code seems to work fine: `urlParams = new URLSearchParams('&iTicket_ID=11'); urlParams.get("iTicket_ID")` returns `11`